# Regex any alphanumeric sequence except a specific string

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to match anything containing `foo<sequence of alphanumeric or space>baz` except `foo<sequence of alphanumeric or space>barbaz`

So this would match:

```
foohello there baz
foobarmystringbaz
```

And this must not match

```
foohellobarbaz
```

I currently have `.*\b(foo[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+baz)\b.*` which is working fine. But I am stumped trying to add the restriction.

**EDIT**:
I am trying to get a capture group to get the matching part, so

```
foohellobaz barbaz
```

should match, but only capture `foohellobaz`

Comment: Language/tool? 

Comment: @JohnyL python - but I'm more interested in the generic regex than specifically python

Comment: Is it standalone string or a string inside a string?

Comment: Looks like you are using `re.match`. Use `re.search(r'\bfoo[a-zA-Z0-9\s]*?baz\b(?<!barbaz)', text)`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/yXCSdB/1)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you mean the string may never end with barbaz. This is done using the following regex:

```
\bfoo[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+(?<!bar)baz\b
```

https://regex101.com/r/8EggsE/2

EDIT:

I updated the regex to match 'foohellobaz' in 'foohellobaz barbaz'.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add another one (with a neg. lookahead):

```
^(?!.*barbaz$)foo[\w ]+baz$
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/7iNE63/2/).

---

As @Harm van der Warl points out, `\w` does include an underscore as well and is the same as `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. This may or may not what you want.

Comment: This doesn't use word boundary. You also match alphanumeric + underscore. Underscore is not valid in this context.

Comment: @HarmvanderWal: There is no need to use a word boundary as OP is speaking of the whole string. I used anchors to ensure the start and end of the string. Regarding the `_` you're probably right, I'll update the answer.

Comment: By using your anchors it can't be mid-string. I'm not sure if that's intended. Maybe it is though.

Comment: Sorry I updated my question - as I am trying to capture the "correct" bit it should also match `foohellobaz barbaz` but capture `foohellobaz`. Sorry that was unclear.